# Django decorator from middleware with different args per view function

Tags: python, django, python-decorators, django-middleware

I have an SSO middleware in my Django project, to which I need to pass an argument.

In my `views.py` file I have different view functions which all get decorated with `decorator_from_middleware_with_args` but have different arguments:

```
sso_decorator = decorator_from_middleware_with_args(SSOMiddleware)

@sso_decorator(True):
def index():
    ...

@sso_decorator(False):
def view():
    ...
```

And here is my middleware class:

```
class SSOMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, some_arg=False):
        self.some_arg = some_arg

    def process_request(self, request):
        print self.some_arg
```

When I access the index view via url, the output that I get in the console is:

```
Some argument: False
Some argument: True
```

I have two questions here:

Why is the process_request function executed twice?
Why does it have a different argument?

Comment: Do you get `Some argument: False` twice if you access the view `view`? Your `SSOMiddleware` is most probably placed in the settings.py, so it get executed every time a request is made. That is the first output. The second output should come from the particular view `index` you access via url. This is my assumption. I find the middlewares a little bit tricky and have my problems with them too.

Comment: Is that middleware also referenced in the middleware settings?

Comment: yes and yes. @DanielRoseman that seems to be it, once I removed it from settings.py it prints only once. Just realized that I don't need it the middleware in the settings.